# SQL substract string using SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX

Tags: sql

I have the following string:

```
'{Mapi-Reply-Recipient-Smtp-Proxies=, Mapi-Non-Receipt-Notification-Requested=true, Message-ID=<6a2k4081-f6134-4345c-b232429-a32410de78@abd.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results=vadmzmail2342.test.com'
```

and I would like to extract ONLY the MessageID part:

```
<6a2k4081-f6134-4345c-b232429-a32410de78@abd.local.test.global>
```

I've tried unsuccessfully to use substring and charindex functions:

```
   SELECT SUBSTRING('{Mapi-Reply-Recipient-Smtp-Proxies=, Mapi-Non-Receipt-Notification-Requested=true, Message-ID=<6a2k4081-f6134-4345c-b232429-a32410de78@abd.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results=vadmzmail2342.test.com',
   (SELECT CHARINDEX(' Message-ID=<','{Mapi-Reply-Recipient-Smtp-Proxies=, Mapi-Non-Receipt-Notification-Requested=true, Message-ID=<6a2k4081-f6134-4345c-b232429-a32410de78@abd.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results=vadmzmail2342.test.com')),
   (SELECT CHARINDEX('>, Authentication-Results', '{Mapi-Reply-Recipient-Smtp-Proxies=, Mapi-Non-Receipt-Notification-Requested=true, Message-ID=<6a2k4081-f6134-4345c-b232429-a32410de78@abd.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results=vadmzmail2342.test.com')))
```

and the result to my query is:

```
 Message-ID=<6a2k4081-f6134-4345c-b232429-a32410de78@abd.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results=vadmzmail2342.test.com
```

What I am doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd argument to SUBSTRING is a LENGTH.  Your statement is passing in the character position...

```
SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )
```

try this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING('{Mapi-Reply-Recipient-Smtp-Proxies=, Mapi-Non-Receipt-Notification-Requested=true, Message-ID=<6a2k4081-f6134-4345c-b232429-a32410de78@abd.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results=vadmzmail2342.test.com',
(SELECT CHARINDEX(' Message-ID=<','{Mapi-Reply-Recipient-Smtp-Proxies=, Mapi-Non-Receipt-Notification-Requested=true, Message-ID=<6a2k4081-f6134-4345c-b232429-a32410de78@abd.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results=vadmzmail2342.test.com')),
CHARINDEX('>, Authentication-Results', '{Mapi-Reply-Recipient-Smtp-Proxies=, Mapi-Non-Receipt-Notification-Requested=true, Message-ID=<6a2k4081-f6134-4345c-b232429-a32410de78@abd.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results=vadmzmail2342.test.com')
-
CHARINDEX(' Message-ID=<','{Mapi-Reply-Recipient-Smtp-Proxies=, Mapi-Non-Receipt-Notification-Requested=true, Message-ID=<6a2k4081-f6134-4345c-b232429-a32410de78@abd.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results=vadmzmail2342.test.com') 
+1)
```

(the value should be 75 in your example)

Answer (score 1):

It is the Charindex function. Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx. Charindex gets the first occurrance index of the character so a

```
   select CHARINDEX('A','TESTING A LETTER')
```

The above will return 9 and if you do a substring, the substring will start from 9, not from the end of the string.

For your query, the solution is below;

```
  DECLARE @String varchar(500) = '{Mapi-Reply-Recipient-Smtp-Proxies=, Mapi-Non-Receipt-Notification-Requested=true, Message-ID=<6a2k4081-f6134-4345c-b232429-a32410de78@abd.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results=vadmzmail2342.test.com'

  SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,
   CHARINDEX('Message-ID=<',@String) + 12,
   CHARINDEX('>',@String,CHARINDEX('Message-ID=<',@String)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: 
Add a REPLACE:

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING('{Mapi-Reply-Recipient-Smtp-Proxies=, Mapi-Non-Receipt-Notification- 
Requested=true, Message-ID=<6a2k4081-f6134-4345c-b232429-a32410de78@abd.local.test.global>, 
Authentication-Results=vadmzmail2342.test.com', (SELECT CHARINDEX(' Message-ID=<','{Mapi-Reply-
Recipient-Smtp-Proxies=, Mapi-Non-Receipt-Notification-Requested=true, Message-ID=<6a2k4081-f6134-
4345c-b232429-a32410de78@abd.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results=vadmzmail2342.test.com')),
(SELECT CHARINDEX('>, Authentication-Results', '{Mapi-Reply-Recipient-Smtp-Proxies=, Mapi-Non-
Receipt-Notification-Requested=true, Message-ID=<6a2k4081-f6134-4345c-b232429-
a32410de78@abd.local.test.global>, Authentication-Results=vadmzmail2342.test.com'))) ,' Message-ID=  
<','')
```

Comment: Using this method, I get the following results: , Message-ID=<6a2k4081-f6134-4345c-b232429-a32410de78@abd.local.test.global>,   Authentication-Results=vadmzmail2342.test.com